# Accessing the model inside an exception filter?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've been trying to create a custom exception filter which handles a specific type of controller exception and returns the same view that corresponds to the action in which the exception occurred with the same model and date and attaches some extra information to TempData that I would like to handle on the front end via JavaScript.

However the exception context doesn't have access to most of these things. Essentially I've been trying to return a new ViewResult and populate it with the data of the model but I simply can't find a reliable way to get the model related to the current action. Redirecting works but is not an option for me as I don't just want to return to the same page, I want to have it populated with any data that the user entered.

Is there any reliable way of achieving this? If not via filters than perhaps via middleWare?

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ExceptionHandled && context.Exception is ValidationException)
            {
                ViewResult result;
                ViewDataDictionary viewData;
                var actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
                //Example message to send to the user.
                var message = context.Exception.Message;
                //This is an antipattern. It makes discerning a class's dependencies harder.
                var tempDataFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITempDataDictionaryFactory>();

                result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = actionName
                };

                viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());

                result.TempData = tempDataFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);
                result.TempData.Add("error", message);
                result.ViewData = viewData;
                context.Result = result;
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }

            base.OnException(context);
        }
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a try / catch block with multiple catch cases, and one will be for the exception you are looking for? In that catch you should be able to run any code needed to clean up and return the view with updated data.

Comment: Do you mean inside the controller? I want to have this logic for all my view controllers. I'd like to handle certain exceptions and reload the view on which they occured and for all else just return an Error page.

Comment: I believe you can get everything you need using dependency injection. Add this to you filter: `public MyFilter(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) => httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;`. When you configure your services call `AddHttpContextAccessor()`